# data not as expected in testcafe and redux-persist app. Data exists in manual test, not populated during Testcafe execution

Tags: redux, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

Data in sharedLocalStorage while executing in Testcafe doesn't match expected, i.e as verified in manual execution of redux-persist app.

Debug mode - stepping through testcafe test at application log in event, I see expected API calls (graphql), then dev tools network tab data refreshes and data in the app is missing.

I've reviewed related redux-persist issues here wondering about issues loading data from sharedLocalStorage.

The current project uses roles / preserveURL, but I disabled them to isolate. Still an issue. I doubt it's related to roles.

```
    await t
      .expect(this.txtEmailInput.value)
      .eql('', 'input is empty')
      .typeText(this.txtEmailInput, 'testis@test.com', {
        replace: true,
        paste: true
      })
      .expect(this.txtPasswordInput.value)
      .eql('', 'input is empty')
      .typeText(this.txtPasswordInput, 'Testing123', {
        replace: true,
        paste: true
      })
      .click(this.btnSignIn);
  },{ preserveUrl: true });
```

```
response in app is:

<div class = "userData"> == $0
    <br>
    ", "
       </div>
      </div>


Should be:
<div class = "userData"> == $0
    "123 someaddress"
    <br>
    "sometown"
    ", "
    "State"
    "12345"
       </div>
      </div>
```

No error messages other than expected from failed assertions due to not - Truthy missing data.  I fear I haven't provided enough, but this is what I have currently.

Answer (score 2):

Likely, you encountered [this](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3780) problem. Our team is researching ways to fix it. As an immediate workaround, you can try the approach suggested [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3780#issuecomment-496955368).

The fix was included in TestCafe [v1.5.0](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v150-2019-9-12).